# if condition ignoring else

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, autofilter

I am trying to find blank cells in column "Issuer", and if there are blank cells, it should show rows with blank cells and a message box indicating there are blank cells however if there no blank cells, nothing should happen(no pop up message).

I have below code which is doing what's intended to do, however the pop-up message always appears even if there is no blanks.

Else statement is being ignored. Really appreciate your help.

Summary of the code:

**1) filter for all asset classes except cash in column 8
2) filter on column "Issuer" for blanks,
if there are blank fields - message should pop-up that there are blanks
if there are no blank fields, reset the filter and continue**

```
Sub Filter()

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Dim ws As Object

ActiveSheet.Range("H:H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>Cash", Operator:=xlAnd

SearchCol = "Issuer"

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    With ws.Range("A2")
        If .AutoFilter(Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="") Then
            MsgBox ("Blank Coupan Rate")
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
        End If
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: [Range.AutoFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) returns a `Range` object, so the condition is incomplete. What are you trying to express? Make the code say it explicitly. Also `On Error Resume Next` used like this is likely to hide problems and cause weird unexpected behavior. Errors are left unhandled until the condition evaluated to false, and then they're ignored until the scope exits... in theory. `On Error GoTo 0` would properly restore error handling.

Comment: Also why late bind `ws`? Declare it `As Worksheet` and you'll get compile-time validation for its member calls.

Comment: i added some explanation and it messed up the format :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're going for with your filter, and what you're defining as a *blank cell*. Excel's definition of a blank cell has an empty value (`null`) which would mean any value with `=""` or `0` would **not** be considered blank.

Assuming that's what you're also defining as blank as Excel, then you can use the built in worksheet function `countBlank` test for blanks. The challenge I'm guessing you are dealing with is testing the proper range (you seem to be using a condition tied to filter which doesn't seem correcT)

In the below example you can see a test macro that searches in column H for blanks and displays.  You could probably leverage something like this with what you have to test what range you're using or where the issue is.

```
Sub exampleTHis()

Dim ws As Worksheet, testRange As Range, aCount As Long, zAnswer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set testRange = Intersect(ws.Range("H:H"), ws.UsedRange)

    If Not testRange Is Nothing Then
        
        aCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(testRange)
        If aCount > 0 Then
         'blank cells found....
            zAnswer = MsgBox(aCount & " blank values found in at " & ws.Name & testRange.Address & ".  Continue macro?", vbYesNo)
            
            If zAnswer = vbNo Then Exit For
            
        End If
    End If
    
Next ws

End Sub
```

Excel does have a countblank function which could easily be used to test your range of data, the only question is if

Comment: thank you, so when I test this code, it says 559 bank values in range 1 to 53960, however i only have 108 blank cells and my range goes to 53509, so its counting correctly but not sure why going extra range (53960-53509+108 = 559)..so strange ....blank cells essentially means no value where 0 is considered a value

Comment: the bank cells works, however I have a initial filter which excludes "cash" from column H. Blank cell logic should be applied after that filter, however its applying to all data.

Comment: @Tartans then you need to modify the range it's checking against to be what you're intending. I would avoid using filter feature, there's other ways to filter directly using vba.

Comment: I am using this: 
    ActiveSheet.Range("H:H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>Cash", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
is there a way I can replace filter feature and still show data excluding "cash" in column H ?